# Flutter | Unable to load asset

Tags: android, flutter

The error, the code and all the other stuff in the screenshot seems to be correct, I noticed that when I first run, the image was displayed without errors, but when I restarted, the error started to appear.

flutter doctor - did not complain about anything

flutter clean - did not help, the error remained

[image]

Comment: have you referenced the `asset` folder in `yaml` file?

Comment: Yes, pubspec.yaml on screenshot

Comment: The first error in your screen shot says "assets" instead of "asset". Could that be part of the problem? I think we need to see more code.

Comment: I renamed the folder with assets to assets, and everywhere there is an asset - renamed to assets, it did not help

This is very strange, I don't have an assets folder anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the indentation for assets

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - asset/images/google.png
```

More details:

```
flutter:

[2 whitespaces or 1 tab]assets:
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- asset/images/google.png
```

After completing the operations, you can run it again. If the problem is not resolved, you can also check the following links. I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.

1. https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/232/unable-to-load-asset-error/
2. https://www.flutterbeads.com/unable-to-load-asset-in-flutter/

Comment: I apologize, but no need to copy and paste someone else's answer here, the screenshot shows perfectly that I have the correct syntax, and indents